# Plot order in ggplot by colour and not alphabertical

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following code which splits the ggplot by color. Instead of the x axis to be plotted alphabetically is there an easy way to group the bars together so the red bar for example are next to each other? Manually moving them would not be an option as I have many more variables - cheers. [image]

```
mydata <- data.frame(x = c("a", "d", "c", "q", "e", "s", "r", "b"), 
        n = c("UK","EUR","UK", "UK", "EUR", "GLB", "GLB", "EUR"), 
        F = c(-6, 17, 26, -37, 44, -22, 15, 12)) 

ggplot(mydata, aes(x = x, y = F, colour = n, fill =n)) + geom_bar(stat = "Identity")
```

Comment: not sure what you want since you didnt provide any CODE and DESIRED OUTPUT. Mabye fill=factor(country) instead of color helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it is what you want.

I guess you are plotting bar charts, and the bars are currently in alphabetical order like the following example,

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

sample_data <- data.frame(
    city = letters[1:5], 
    value = c(10, 11, 17, 12, 13), 
    country = c("c1", "c2", "c1", "c1", "c2")
)
ggplot(sample_data) + 
    geom_col(aes(x=city, y=value, colour=country, fill=country))
```

The order of the bars (left to right) is a, b, c, d, e. However, you want the bars ordered by `country` (the variable determines the colours/fill), i.e. a (c1), c (c1), d (c1), b (c2), e (c2).

To do this, you can set the 'correct' order of `city` using `factor(city, levels=...)`. Since you want to sort city by country, the levels would be `city[order(country)]`.

```
sample_data <- sample_data %>% 
    mutate(city2 = factor(city, levels=city[order(country)]))
ggplot(sample_data) + 
    geom_col(aes(x=city2, y=value, colour=country, fill=country))
```

Comment: Thanks can the above be done with the following code? I get a duplicated levels in factors error.                                                                 sample_data <- data.frame(
+     city = c("a", "b", "c","d", "a", "b", "c", "d"), 
+     value = c(10, 11, 17, 12, 13, 14, 11, 8), type = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
+     country = c("c1", "c2", "c1", "c1", "c2", "c2", "c1", "c1"))

Comment: @user8491385 You got duplicated levels error because city was not distinct, both country 'c1' and 'c2' had city 'a' and thus city[order(country)] got two 'a'. To handle this data, you may need to create a new country_city variable, depending what you want to draw.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
library(tidyverse)
mydata %>% 
  mutate(x1 = factor(x, levels=x[order(n,F)])) %>% 
   ggplot(aes(x = x1, y = F, colour = n, fill =n)) + 
   geom_col()
```

[image]